graphQl doesn't support attachments?
I'm trying to query the attachments related to a record like this:
query getAttachments($recordId: ID) {
    uiapi {
        query {
                Attachment ( where: {
                                and: [
                                    { ParentId: { eq: $recordId } }
                                    { ContentType: { eq: "audio/wav"}} 
                                    ]
                                },
                                orderBy: { CreatedDate: { order: ASC }}
                                ) {
                    edges {
                          node {
                            Id
                            Name { value }
                            ContentType { value }                        
                          }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

When I execute the above in Postman, I'm getting this error:
{
    "data": {},
    "errors": [
        {
            "extensions": {
                "ErrorType": "ValidationError"
            },
            "locations": [
                {
                    "column": 17,
                    "line": 4
                }
            ],
            "message": "Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'Attachment' in type 'RecordQuery' is undefined @ 'uiapi/query/Attachment'",
            "paths": []
        }
    ]
}

So, I can't use graphQL to query attachments?

from documentation of graphql documentation

The GraphQL wire adapter manages your data using Lightning Data
Service (LDS).

from Lightning Data Service documentation

Lightning Data Service supports all custom objects and all the
standard objects that User Interface API supports. Custom metadata
types are not supported. Lightning Data Service doesn’t incur any API
usage calls, but it is subject to general limits like the numbers of
records returned.

here is a list of standard objects supported by User Interface API
Attachment is not listed there. However, ContentDocument, ContentDocumentLink, and ContentVersion are there. You can try to use them.

Unfortunately, my client is using Attachments.  Thanks for clarifying, though!
